# How can you get the display adapter used for a particular monitor in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

On a Mac, I can use the following to print out the adapter used for a particular monitor:

```
io_registry_entry_t dspPort = CGDisplayIOServicePort(displays[i]);
CFDataRef model_;
model_ = (CFDataRef)IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(dspPort,kIOServicePlane,CFSTR("model"),
                                                    kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    kIORegistryIterateRecursively | kIORegistryIterateParents);

if (model_) {
  newLine();
  String model((const char*)CFDataGetBytePtr(model_), CFDataGetLength(model_));
  log.printf("Adapter: %s", model.buf);
  CFRelease(model_);
}
```

**Example output-    Adapter: AMD Radeon HD 6750M**

Where `displays[i]` is populated using `CGGetActiveDisplayList(nDisplays, displays, &nDisplays);`

Is there any way to do the equivalent operation on Windows? I'm cycling through all displays using `EnumDisplayMonitors`.

I can get a list of adapters using `EnumDisplayDevices`, but how do I see which monitor is attached to which adapter?

**Edit**

Using:

```
for (int i=0; EnumDisplayDevicesA(monitorInfo.szDevice, i, &dev, 0); i++) {
    newLine();
    log.printf("Display Device: %s",(char*)dev.DeviceString);
  }
```

I can get the device names of the monitors themselves, but not the adapters they are connected to!

Comment: Out of curiousity (since you just accepted my answer): which route (if any) did you go for?

Comment: I didn't get any further. Win32_VideoController looked promising, but it's a minor issue so I've left it for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three approaches:

1. The [`EnumDisplayDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation mentions that the `dwFlags` argument can be used to get a device ID which can be used with the [SetupAPI functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That API provide a whole range of functions to [get device information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553567%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#ddk_setupdi_device_information_functions_dg). So maybe you can get the device ID from `EnumDisplayDevices`, stick that into some SetupAPI function to get the monitor device struct, and get the display adapter device ID from there.
2. You can probably use the [`Win32_VideoController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class via WMI to get the display adapter information.
3. I can imagine that some DirectX API is available for getting information about the installed graphics hardware.

Comment: Nice options. Can you please tell me If i'm implementing using C++ WMI-ACPI interface(Win32_VideoController) then how may i get number of instance?