# In Vulkan how can you associate each individual video card with monitors they're directly connected to

Tags: graphics, 3d, vulkan

I have two monitors, each connected to a different GPU. Both GPUs are in a single machine, and I want to run a single application. I have two independent views, and I would like to render each one using a GPU/Monitor set. I can create multiple surfaces and devices, but I want to ensure I associate each surface with the GPU its monitor is plugged into, otherwise I suspect I'll suffer performance issues as the frame buffers need to be copied back and forth between cards.

I'm using fullscreen surfaces, and I was thinking this was something `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR` would tell me. However, both `VkSurfaceKHR` appear to be valid targets for each `VkPhysicalDevice` so I guess this is something the OS and GPU Driver can handle, but is there any hint about which surface is optimal to associate with a device?

From what I can tell the extension `VK_KHR_display` is one way of doing this, but it's not available on my Windows 10 machine or Nvidia GPU. It seems to be intended for embedded platforms only. However it lets you list attached displays for each device which is pretty much what I'm looking for: https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.30.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch29s03.html

This quote from the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_win32_surface) makes me belive this may not be supported on Windows:

> Issues
>
> 1) Does Win32 need a way to query for compatibility between a particular physical device and a specific screen? Compatibility between a physical device and a window generally only depends on what screen the window is on. However, there is not an obvious way to identify a screen without already having a window on the screen.
>
> RESOLVED: No. While it may be useful, there is not a clear way to do this on Win32. However, a method was added to query support for presenting to the windows desktop as a whole.

However, I'm still interested in hearing if there's a work around to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: How do you intend to ensure that a particular window stays on a particular monitor?

Comment: by creating borderless fullscreen windows. I haven't confirmed yet if it's possible to create two true fullscreen windows (one for each monitor) but I don't care about traditional windowing for this application, locking the views in place is perfectly fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured out a work around for this:

Direct X actually supports this through use of the `IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs` function. This lets you list the monitors connected to each GPU. Then using these two extensions you can remap this information to Vulkan:

- [VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities)
- [VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2)

You can use these to get the `deviceLUID` from `VkPhysicalDeviceIDPropertiesKHR`.
This can then be compared with the Luid from this structure in Direct X `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC`

You can also use `glfwGetWin32Window` to get the `HWND` of the monitor. This lets you associate a vulkan surface with a direct x monitor.

You now have all the information you need to accociate vulkan surfaces with the devices they're actually connected to.

At least in my application, setting this up correctly results in a significant difference in performance.

This would all be way simpler (and cross platform) if Windows would just support the `VK_KHR_display` and  `VK_KHR_display_swapchain` extensions as [Linux does](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114240/en-us).

Answer (score 1):

There are two extensions that are useful for such things: the one mentioned by You, `VK_KHR_display` and the second called `VK_KHR_display_swapchain` which allows You to create a swapchain directly on a device’s display without any underlying window system.

But these extensions are rarely supported on Windows. In core Vulkan API there is no way to achieve what You want. And I'm afraid You need to use OS-specific functions (You need to rely on the WinAPI functions in this situation).

[EDIT]

Did You saw this question? [How can you get the display adapter used for a particular monitor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793971/how-can-you-get-the-display-adapter-used-for-a-particular-monitor-in-windows) If not, maybe it will help You start with Your research.

Answer (score 0):

As you already discovered, on Win32 you need to use the OS windowing system to pick the display you want to use, using the  Window API. It can be straight forward.

BUT if you intend to make simple and agnostic OS code, check GLFW project. It has high level functions to handle windows on all major OSs.

Check :

[GLFW monitor Guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/monitor_guide.html)

[GLFW Vulkan integration](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/vulkan_guide.html)

> **GLFW on its own words:**
>
> GLFW is a free, Open Source, multi-platform library for OpenGL, OpenGL ES and Vulkan application development. It provides a simple, platform-independent API for creating windows, contexts and surfaces, reading input, handling events, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using GLFW, but I'm also willing to ditch that abstraction if it doesn't handle my special case. The particular issue here is not creating windows and picking displays, it's *associating those displays with the GPUs they're physically connected to*. If you can do this you should be able to avoid some overhead in copying frame buffers back and forth between cards, assuming each card's output is independent of the other.

Comment: Got it. You have a very special case where you have two different GPUs with independent output, with some chance to happen a cross display. I guess the main issue would be the app using the weak card (onboard Intel) instead the powerful one (discrete AMD/Nvidia). The cross display may not be a big issue, as they are all translated to 2D images and draws by windowing system. Please, this are my assumptions, please check docs and test it, if necessary.